# How to scale x axis graph in c3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

```js
var chart = c3.generate({
bindto: '#chart',
    data: {
        x: 'x',
        columns: [
            ['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03'],
            ['data1', 30, 200, 100],
            ['data2', 130, 340, 200]
        ]
    },
    axis: {
        x: {
            type: 'timeseries',
            tick: {
                format: '%Y-%m-%d'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div id="chart"></div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.4.10/c3.min.js"></script>
```

I need to change the graph to 5 points '2013-01-01' to  '2013-01-05' and scale the graph.

FROM:

```
['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03'],
['data1', 30, 200, 100],
['data2', 130, 340, 200]
```

TO:

```
['x', '2013-01-01', '2013-01-02', '2013-01-03', '2013-01-04', '2013-01-05'],
['data1', 30, 115, 200, 150, 100],
['data2', 130, 235, 340, 270, 200]
```

Is this possible in c3?

Comment: Do you want to make this change after some event or a period of time after an initial drawing?

Comment: After some event. My question is not about changing the data it's about scaling the data to match the new x-axis